# Close Modal after click on submit button (ajax sucess)

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I know this is question already asked a few times in StackOverflow but I cannot make it work in my case with the suggestions given.

So basically I have this modal in my view:

```
<div id="createFolderModal" class="modal">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <!- (...) -->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
            <!- (...) -->
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="createFolder()">Create</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This modal is opened with a button click:

```
$('#newFolderButton').on('click', function () {
        $('#createFolderModal').show();
    });
```

Then my script is:

```
function createFolder() {
        // (...)

        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: '@Url.Action("CreateFolder", "ManageFiles")',
            data: { name: path },
            dataType: "json",
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                //close the modal
                $('#createFolderModal').modal('hide');
                //$('#createFolderModal').modal('toggle');

                document.getElementById("inputFolderName").value = ""; // to empty the input field
            }
        });
    }
```

So, as you can see I already tried the instructions below but none worked. On all posts about this on StackOverflow, this are the only suggestions, so I don't know what can be wrong in my case.

```
$('#createFolderModal').modal('hide');
$('#createFolderModal').modal('toggle');
```

Also tried data-dismiss="modal" inside my button and didn't work.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you check with this `$('#createFolderModal').removeClass('show');`

Comment: How about `$('#createFolderModal').hide();` ?

Comment: If you want to close modal you have to use `modal("show")` or `modal("hide")`. not `show()` / `hide()` method

Comment: @BasantaMatia Thanks for your suggestion but it didn't work in my case.

Comment: @Ignatius Many thanks, it worked!

Comment: @PankajMakwana can you give more details why Ignatius suggestion is not a good practice? It worked in my case. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correct way to close modal is here http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
$('#createFolderModal').modal();
```

use

```
$('#createFolderModal').show(); to open the dialog
```

and then

```
$('#createFolderModal').modal('hide'); to hide it.
```

Comment: @myusername21 try this solution

Comment: @myusername21, this is how bootstrap recommends it.